# Regex - Consecutive symbols

Tags: php, regex

I want to know if it is possible to make a single regular expression that checks if a username is valid depending on these rules:

- 3 to 12 characters
- Can have uppercase and/or lowercase characters
- Can have numeric characters
- Can have '_' and '-' symbols

I know how to do the above, but what I want to check in the same regex is if the username contains consecutive symbols (eg. user__name or user--name)

Is this possible or does it require 2 regex checks?

Comment: Should the username be considered invalid if it contains consecutive symbols?

Comment: Yes, it should be considered invalid.

Comment: What about `user_-name`? Does it matter if it is the same consecutive symbol?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I meant all consecutive symbols, just not 2 of the same in a row.

Comment: Probably possible, but consider other approaches that would be easier to read and maintain than one regular expression that has multiple responsibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off with two regex checks, if anything for code readability. Regexes are hard to read already, you don't need to make it even harder on yourself by making one complicated regex instead of two simple ones.

```
preg_match("(^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}$)",$username) && !preg_match("([-_]{2})",$username)
```

Comment: Does the second z need to be capitalised, or does that not matter?

Comment: My bad, the Shift key on my keyboard is touchy. Yes, it should be uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12})(?!.*[-_]{2,})
```

might work

Comment: That would prevent duplicate consecutive letters as well.

Comment: Wasn't that obvious that duplicate letters should be allowed.

Comment: To match any two consecutive symbols as the OP required this should be `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12})(?!.*([-_]){2,})`, and is the way I would code it. +1

Comment: Thanks Borodin, I hate it when the requirements change with every comment :/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
preg_match('^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9_-])(?!\1)){3,12}$', $username);
```

It checks whether all the characters are letters, numbers, _ or -, and if theres the same letter afterwards. `(?!\1)` means "matches if the string afterwards is not equal (`(?! ... )`) to the first capturing subpattern (`\1`), which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If we break down your expression in a textual manner your expression breaks down to:

```
^                    start of input
[_-]?                optional _ | - at the start
[a-zA-Z0-9]+         at least a number of alphanumeric characters
([_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*  followed an optional repeating group of _ | - and more alphanumerics
[_-]?                optional _ | - at the end.
$                    end of input
```

As you can see no look arounds or anything are needed to validate your requirements if you keep strictly to the way the text is formatted.

This expression doesn't take the length of the username into account, it's usually easier to do add a second validation to check that.

Optionally you can put a (?=.{3,12}$) after the ^ to incorporate the length validation into the expression as well.

```
^                    start of input
(?=.{3,12}$)         length validation
[_-]?                optional _ | - at the start
[a-zA-Z0-9]+         at least a number of alphanumeric characters
([_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*  followed an optional repeating group of _ | - and more alphanumerics
[_-]?                optional _ | - at the end.
$                    end of input
```